# how to take in two rational inputs on the same line?

Tags: c++, class, input, istream

Main goal is to take user input in one line and perform arithmetic and comparisons. The function is equal must compare two rationals and see if they are equal or not. However, I am not sure how I would take in both numbers at the same time. I thought about doing something with istream but I am not sure how to do this.

ex: Enter two rationals to compare: 
1/4 3/5

they are not equal!

Any help is appreciated.

```
// Add appropriate headers

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


/*  KEEP THIS COMMENT
* class Rational
*    represents a Rational number. Remember rational means ratio-nal
*    which means there is a numerator and denominator having
*    integer values. Using good ADT techniques, we have made member
*    variable private (also known as instance variables) and made member
*    functions public.
*/
class Rational
{
 private:   
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
  static int counter;
  //int gcd (int a, int b);



 public:
    /*
    // ToDo: Default Constructor
    Rational();

    // ToDo: Constructor that takes int numerator
    Rational(int num);

    // ToDo: Constructor that takes int numerator and int denominator
    Rational(int num, int den);
    */
    // Three constructors to one 
    Rational(int num = 0, int den = 1);


    // ToDo: Member function to read a rational in the form: n/d
    void input();

    // ToDo: Member function to write a rational as n/d
    void output()const;

    // ToDo: declare an accessor function to get the numerator
    int getNumerator()const;

    // ToDo: declare an accessor function to get the denominator
    int getDenominator()const;

    // object counter 'global'
    static int getObjectCounter();

    // ToDo: delcare a function called Sum that takes two rational objects
    // sets the current object to the sum of the given objects using the
    // formula: a/b + c/d = ( a*d + b*c)/(b*sd)
    friend Rational sum(const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    friend Rational product(const Rational &a, const Rational &b);

    void set(int num, int den);

    //void simplify(int num, int den);

    friend bool isEqual(const Rational &a, const Rational &b);



};
```

```
// Add appropriate headers

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "rational7.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



// ToDO: Implement your class member functions below.

/*
Rational::Rational()
{
   numerator = 0;
   denominator = 1;
}

Rational::Rational(int num)
{
   numerator = num;
   denominator = 1;
}

Rational::Rational(int num, int den)
{
   Rational r; 
   numerator = num;
   denominator = den;
}
*/

int Rational::counter = 0;

//Three constructors to one 
Rational::Rational(int num, int den)
{
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}

Rational sum(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
//void Rational::sum(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;
   int num = 0;
   int den = 0;

   //num = (a.getNumerator()*b.getDenominator() + a.getDenominator()*b.getNumerator());
   //den = (a.getDenominator()*b.getDenominator());
   num = (a.numerator*b.denominator + a.denominator*b.numerator);
   den = (a.denominator*b.denominator);

   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;

}

//void Rational::product(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
Rational product(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
   Rational temp;

   //int num = (a.getNumerator()*b.getNumerator());
   //int den = (a.getDenominator()*b.getDenominator());
   int num = (a.numerator*b.numerator);
   int den = (a.denominator*b.denominator);
   temp.numerator = num;
   temp.denominator = den;

   return temp;
}
void Rational::input()
{
   string in;
   getline(cin, in);
   //cin >> in;
   // find the index position of /
   int indx = in.find("/");
   // seperate the numerator
   numerator = atoi(in.substr(0, indx).c_str());
   // seperate the denominator
   denominator = atoi(in.substr(indx+1, in.length()).c_str());
   //if(denominator != 0)
   Rational(numerator, denominator);

}

void Rational::output()const
{
   cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}


void Rational::set(int num, int den)
{
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}



// Two getter functions
int Rational::getNumerator()const
{
   return numerator;
}

int Rational::getDenominator()const
{
   return denominator;
}

/*
void Rational::simplify(int num, int den)
{
    gcd(num, den);
}



int Rational::gcd (int a, int b)
{
   while (a!=0 && b!=0)
   {
      a = a % b;
      if (a!=0)
         b = b % a;
   }
   if (a==0)
      return b;
   if (b==0)
      return a;
}
*/


bool isEqual(const Rational &a, const Rational &b)
{
  if (a.numerator * b.denominator == a.denominator * b.numerator)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}


int Rational::getObjectCounter()
{
    return counter;
}
```

```
// Add appropriate headers

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "rational7.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // ToDo: declare three rational objects using the default constructor
    Rational a, b, c;
    int length;
    char answer='Y';

    // Main loop to read in rationals and compute the sum
    do {
        cout << "Enter the number of fractions to add/multiply: ";
        cin >> length;
        Rational *fractions = new Rational[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
          fractions[i].set (1,i+1);
          fractions[i].output();
          cout << " " << endl;
        }



        Rational r_sum, r_product(1);
        //tempsum = fractions[0];
        //tempproduct = fractions[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
          r_sum = sum(r_sum, fractions[i]); // test r.sum
          r_product = product(r_product, fractions[i]); // test
        }
        //simplify


         cout << "Sum of fractions: "; 
         r_sum.output();
         cout << " " << endl;
         cout << "Prod of fractions: "; 
         r_product.output();
         cout << " " << endl;
        // ToDo: use your input member function to read the first rational

        ifstream input1;
        string one;
        string two;
        cout << "Enter two rationals to compare: ";
        input1 >> one >> two;

        //a.input();
        //b.input();
        a.output(); // Debug line
        cout << " " << endl; // Debug line
        b.output(); // Debug line
        /*
        while (a.getDenominator() == 0 || b.getDenominator() == 0)
        {
            cout << "wrong input. \n";
            cout << "Enter a rational (p/q): \n";
            a.input();
            b.input();
        }s
        */

        if (isEqual(a, b) == true)
        {
            a.output();
            cout << " is equal to ";
            b.output();
        }
        else
        {
            a.output();
            cout << " is not equal to ";
            b.output();
        }
    //  cout << "Total number of objects created = " << << endl;

        cout << "\nTry again (Y/N)?\n";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');

    } while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's minimal. Remove every line of code that's not necessary. You can use `std::cin >> a >> b;`

Comment: You are already using [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). You should read the documentation. You can pass an additional argument for the delimiter. You could read twice until space.

Comment: once I use a.input() to store user input '1/2 3/5' how would i break it up? I only know how to break '1/2' and '3/5'.

Comment: `string in1, in2; getline(cin, in1, ' '); getline(cin, in2);` reads the first number into `in1` and the second number into `in2`. Alternatively you could use `std::cin >> in` instead of `getline`. That would also solve the problem. Why do you use atoi instead of stoi?